# How to call a target when another target fails in NAnt?

Tags: ant, nant, nantcontrib

I have two different tasks say A and B. If A fails I need to call B. How is it possible with NAnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, (for any one who goes across the same issue)

```
<trycatch>
    <try>
        <call target="A" />
    </try>
    <catch>
        <call target="B" />
    </catch>
</trycatch>
```